# JQuery Theme roller

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-templates

I created a theme using http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ all of the ui-widgets are functioning properly with the exception of the icons. I cannot get the hover to work?

I am using and its not triggering hover, any suggestions:

```
<li title=".ui-icon-document" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button must be initialized within the document .ready() function.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $( ".button_name" ).button({ icons: {primary:'ui-icon-document',} });

}); `
```